# Problem with value assignment inside a for loop

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, cs50, memory-access

There is silly bug in my code. I would appreciate to any help. I know this is language (C) specific (because I have some experience with Python & JS).
I'm trying to split source array into two parts.
When I try to assign value of current index of source array to another array, it works fine but only until the end of for loop. After loop completion these arrays turns out with completely different values.
Please check out my code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <cs50.h>

int merge_sort(int unsorted_array[], int size_of_arr);

int main(void)
{
    int unar[] = {9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};     // unsorted array
    int len_of_arr = sizeof(unar) / sizeof(int);  // finding lenght of array
    merge_sort(unar, len_of_arr);                 
}

int merge_sort(int unsorted_array[], int size_of_arr)
{
    // dividing
    int ls_len; // lenght of left side of an array
    int rs_len; // lenght of right side of an array

    if (size_of_arr % 2 == 0) // if lenght of an array is even then lenght of each half equals: lenght of arr / 2
    {
        ls_len = size_of_arr / 2;
        rs_len = size_of_arr / 2;
    }
    else                      // else lenght of arr / 2 and right half++
    {
        ls_len = size_of_arr / 2;
        rs_len = size_of_arr / 2 + 1;
    }

    int unsorted_ls[ls_len]; // unsorted_array_length // 2
    int unsorted_rs[rs_len]; // if array_len is odd ? array_len / 2 + 1 : array_len / 2
    printf("left half len: %i\nRight half len: %i\n", ls_len, rs_len);

    for (int i = 0; i < size_of_arr; i++)
    {
        if (i < ls_len)
        {
            unsorted_ls[i] = unsorted_array[i];
            printf("Current value of original array: %i\n", unsorted_array[i]);
            printf("Currently assigned value of left half: %i\n\n", unsorted_ls[i]);       // current
        } else
        {
            unsorted_rs[i] = unsorted_array[i];
            printf("Current value of original array: %i\n", unsorted_rs[i]);
            printf("Currently assigned value of right half: %i\n\n", unsorted_array[i]);
        }
    }

    printf("Left half outside of for loop: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < ls_len; i++)
    {
        printf("%i", unsorted_ls[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("Right half outside of for loop: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < rs_len; i++)
    {
        printf("%i", unsorted_rs[i]); 
    } 
    printf("\n"); 

    // sorting                                                       // not implemented yet
    // int sorted_left_side[] = merge_sort(unsorted_left_half); 
    // int sorted_right_side[] = merge_sort(unsorted_right_half); 
    
    // merging                                                       // not implemented yet
    // // for (int i = 0; )

    // return sorted_array;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `unsorted_rs[i] = unsorted_array[i];` What index values are allowed for `unsorted_rs`? What values do you use?

Comment: Specified on definition:
int unsorted_ls[ls_len]; 
int unsorted_rs[rs_len];

Comment: I know. That was meant as a hint for you. Allowed are: `0..rs_len-1` while you only assign to it if `i < ls_len` is false with `rs_len` is same as `ls_len` or `ls_len+1`. Clearly out of bounds.

Comment: Yeah, now it's clear. What I can't realize is why unsorted_ls was with incorrect values on the output too?

Comment: Out of bounds access means undefined behaviour. Everything can happen. If you write beyond the limits of an array you could hit memory used by some other variable. If `unsorted_ls` is located in memory just in front of `unsorted_rs` your access could hit `unsorted_ls` instead. You could also hit other variables, counters, return addresses on your stack... Don't expect specific result when invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. C is a strict beast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assignment statement

```
unsorted_rs[i] = unsorted_array[i];
```

invokes undefined behavior because there is an attempt to access memory beyond the array `unsorted_rs` when the value of the index `i` is greater than or equal to `ls_len`.

You should write

```
unsorted_rs[i - ls_len] = unsorted_array[i];
```

Pay attention to that instead of this if-else statement

```
if (size_of_arr % 2 == 0) // if lenght of an array is even then lenght of each half equals: lenght of arr / 2
{
    ls_len = size_of_arr / 2;
    rs_len = size_of_arr / 2;
}
else                      // else lenght of arr / 2 and right half++
{
    ls_len = size_of_arr / 2;
    rs_len = size_of_arr / 2 + 1;
}
```

you could just write

```
ls_len = size_of_arr / 2;
rs_len = size_of_arr - ls_len;
```